# Problemas al llenar un div con un arreglo en react

Tags: reactjs

Buen dia, estoy usando react, quiero intentar llenar un div con un array del cual obtengo la información de mi base de datos, logro llenar el div izquierdo, pero si selecciono el componente se vuelve a llenar el div, la idea es que cuando seleccione el elemento, le de agregar y me lo mande al lado derecho y no se vuelva a llenar. adjunto codigo y fotos

[image: Parte grafica]

Items

```
import React from 'react'
const Items = ({}) => {
    const handleClic = () => {
        handleClick(value)
    }

    return (
        <li className={selected ? 'selected' : ''} onClick={handleClic}>{value}</li> 
} 

export default Items
```

Selects

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Items from './Items'
import {optionservice} from '../../../services/optionservice'

const Selects = () => {
    const [stateOptions, setStateOptions] = useState([])
    const [options, setOptions] = useState(options)
    const [arreglo1, setArreglo1] = useState()
    const [arreglo2, setArreglo2] = useState(null) 

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            optionservice.getAll().then(response => {
                setStateOptions(response) 
            }
        }, 1000)
    }, [])

    const handleSelect = (selectedVal) => {
        setSelected(selectedVal !== selected ? selectedVal: null)
    }

    const handleAdd = () => {
        if (arreglo1.includes(selected)) {
            setArreglo1(arreglo1.filter(val => val !== selected).sort())
            setArreglo2([...arreglo2, selected].sort())
            setSelected(null)         
        }        
    }   

    const handleRemove = () => {
        if (arreglo2.includes(selected)) {
            setArreglo1([...arreglo1, selected].sort())
            setArreglo2(arreglo2.filter(val => val !== selected).sort())
            setSelected(null)         
        }        
    }      

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Asignación de páginas</h1>
            <section>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        {arreglo1.map(val => {
                            return (
                                <Items 
                                    key={val}
                                    handleClick={handleSelect}
                                    value={val}
                                    selected={selected === val} 
                                />
                            )
                        })} 
                    </ul> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={handleAdd}>Agregar</button>
                    <button onClick={handleRemove}>Remover</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        {arreglo2.map(val => {
                            return (
                                <Items 
                                    key={val}
                                    handleClick={handleSelect}
                                    value={val}
                                    selected={selected === val} 
                                />
                            )
                        })} 
                    </ul> 
                </div>
            </section> 
        </>
    )

}

export default Selects
```

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes de código. Edita tu pregunta y agrega tu código en formato de texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la línea 17 de tu componente `Selects` estás mutando directamente tu state `options`. No deberías hacer esto si no que deberías usar su `setOptions` correspondiente.

Ya que el valor de `arreglo1` depende de `options` que a su ves depende de `stateOptions`, dentro de tu `useEffect` en la línea 11, deberías llamar también a `setArreglo1` y `setOptions` y asignarle sus valores correspondientes.

```
const [stateOptions, setStateOptions] = useState([]);
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
const [arreglo1, setArreglo1] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    optionservice.getAll().then(response => {
      setStateOptions(response);
      const options = response.map(i => i.menuItemName);
      setOptions(options);
      setArreglo1(options);
    });
  }, 1000);
}, []);

...
```

También podrías eliminar `stateOptions`  y `options` ya que por lo visto solo los usas como valores intermediarios para terminar seteando el valor de `arreglo1`, en ese caso podrías borrar la declaración de esos 2 state y también sus llamadas a sus setState correspondientes dentro del useEffect.